# SQLite: fastest way to implement Boolean retrieval

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization, information-retrieval, boolean-operations

I have an SQLite table `features` with columns `document` and `feature`.

None of the columns is `UNIQUE`, that is I can do

```
SELECT feature FROM features WHERE document=121;
```

to get all the features of document 121 or

```
SELECT document FROM features WHERE feature=11;
```

to get all the documents with feature 11.

Now I want to ask Boolean retrieval questions like:

*Give me all the documents with features 11, 15, 143, 1222, 2001.*

where the length of the feature list queried is varying.

Of course I have an index on the two columns.

I think with the `INTERSECT` keyword it would query the entire table for each feature instead of understanding the Boolean AND and repeatedly filtering the `document` column by the documents that have all the features so far.

What is the fastest query to model these Boolean AND-connected queries?

Answer (score 0):

First create an index for the column `feature` so that it can be used when you filter the table for the features that you want:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_feature ON features(feature);
```

Then use aggregation like this:

```
SELECT document 
FROM features 
WHERE feature IN (11, 15, 143, 1222, 2001)
GROUP BY document
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5; // the number of features that you want
```

The condition in the `HAVING` clause makes sure that the `document` returned has all 5 `feature`s.